# Move a function dependent on Ajax success callback out of the callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

From JSHint.com:

> Function declarations should not be placed in blocks. Use a function
>   expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

JSHint is telling me to move this function out of the success callback.

```
function matchContainerHeight() {
    var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
    $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
}
setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
$(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);
```

However, I'm not sure how I can do that since `containerHeight` comes from the response itself depending on the height of the container once the response has come back. But then again, I'm not too savvy with JS so maybe there is a way. If so, please help me out. Thank you.

**Here is the full code:**

```
    function openProject() {

        var post_id = $(this).data('id'), // data-id attribute for .post-link
            ajaxURL = site.ajaxURL; // Ajax URL localized from functions.php

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
            success: function(response) {

                $('#project-container').html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function() {

                    resize();

                    // If the user has scrolled...
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {

                        // First scroll the page to the top
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop : 0
                        },400, function() {

                            // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
                            function matchContainerHeight() {
                                var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
                                $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
                            }
                            setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
                            $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);

                        });

                    // If the user has not scrolled...
                    } else {

                        // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
                        function matchContainerHeight() {
                            var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
                            $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
                        }
                        setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
                        $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);

                    }

                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Still you can move `matchContainerHeight` function definition outside `openProject` and call it in `success` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is saying that you *could* move the function outside of the block *or* you can make it in to a function expression, like this:

```
var matchContainerHeight = function() {
    var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
    $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
}
setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
$(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);
```

However given that both your conditions use the same logic, in this instance be best to move it out of the if condition and in to a place within scope of both condition blocks, as suggested by jsHint. Try this:

```
// $.ajax({...
    success: function (response) {
        $('#project-container').html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function () {
            resize();

            // If the user has scrolled...
            if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
                // First scroll the page to the top
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 400, function () {
                    // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
                    matchContainerHeight()
                });
            // If the user has not scrolled...
            } else {
                // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
                matchContainerHeight()
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
// });

function matchContainerHeight() {
    var heightHandler = function() {
        var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
        $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
    }
    setTimeout(heightHandler, 100);
    $(window).on('resize', heightHandler);
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to have the function and variable share the same name?

Comment: @J82 yes, although I agree it would be confusing so I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All JSHint is telling you that you should not put function definition statements directly inside `if`/`else`/`when`/`for` blocks. It won't complain if you do this, and you will get exactly the same functionality:

```
$('#project-container').html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function() {
    // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition       
    function matchContainerHeight() {
        var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
        $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
    }

    resize();

    // If the user has scrolled...
    if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
        // First scroll the page to the top
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : 0
        }, 400, function() {
            setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
            $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);
        });
    } else {
        // If the user has not scrolled...
        setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
        $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);
    }
});
```

`matchContainerHeight` doesn't depend on any of the variables in its enclosing scope, and to make matters worse, you're defining it identically twice. You could move it out of your AJAX callback completely and you would be just fine:

```
 // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
function matchContainerHeight() {
    var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
    $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
}

function scheduleMatchContainerHeight() {
    setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
    $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);
}

function openProject() {
    var post_id = $(this).data('id'), // data-id attribute for .post-link
        ajaxURL = site.ajaxURL; // Ajax URL localized from functions.php

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-container').html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function() {
                resize();

                // If the user has scrolled...
                if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
                    // First scroll the page to the top
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop : 0
                    }, 400, scheduleMatchContainerHeight);
                } else {
                    // If the user has not scrolled...
                    scheduleMatchContainerHeight();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```